# Fluid Container on Browser Downsize

Tags: jquery, css, responsive-design

The website I am currently working on is https://twobyfore.com. There is currently an iframe displaying a Codepen for the hero header, in which sits a div with the id `#lp-code-196`. This div has the styling,

```
position: relative;
width: 100vw;
left: calc(-50vw + 50%);
```

This has worked to fit the div to screen width (on mobile, 13", 17"), however, I have just noticed that upon downsizing the browser width, white gutters start to appear on either side (https://snag.gy/qwE1XH.jpg).

I have attempted to use some jQuery,

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $('#lp-code-196').css('width', $(window).width);
});
```

except this hasn't worked to resolve the width + white gutter issues.

Would anyone know how to rectify this?

Comment: There's no chance at editing the CodePen?

Comment: What editions would you make to the Codepen?

Answer (score 0):

Because your question isn't [minified](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), it's hard to give a complete answer. But **the problem lies in that you have a fixed-width container, `.lp-positioned-content`, and then content inside it, which you're trying to extend *outside its container*.** This is bad practice. Here is an XML version of what you have:

```
<container width="900px">
  <div-that-tries-to-be-100%-screen-width>
  </div-that-tries-to-be-100%-screen-width>
</container>
```

And here's what you should attempt:

```
<div width="100%" position="relative">
  <cool-iframe width="100%" position="absolute"></cool-iframe>
  <container width="900px">
    <header>Top producers aren't satisfied with average.</header>
    ...
  </container>
</div>
```

To start you off:

1. Set the `width` of `#lp-code-196` to `100%` and `left` to `0`.
2. Do the same for `.lp-positioned-content`
3. Create a fixed-width container with `margin: 0 auto` and stuff everything you want to be horizontally centered on the page into it

Comment: So we're using Unbounce to build our pages, and this is the way that they've set up HTML. Going on what you mentioned, I've actually devised a hacky method to get the iframe out of the .lp-positioned-content, and into another div in which the width scales with the body.

Comment: Ironic that most products which advertise `no coding required` or `without IT` often have their users wanting, or asking for IT help anyway. But I'm glad to help. Note: in the future, you might consider mentioning any page generators or frameworks you're using in the question, so you can get more specialized help.

Comment: Great point regarding page-generators/frameworks. I definitely need to work on clarity and substance when I post questions. Thanks once again for pointing me in the right direction!

Answer (score 0):

I haven't pushed it live yet but this is the code that seems to be working well to get rid of the gutters on browser resize.

The JavaScript:

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
    var element = $('#lp-code-196');
    $(element).remove();
    $('#lp-pom-block-8').append(element);
  });
</script>
```

The CSS:

```
  #lp-code-196 {
    z-index: 0;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
  }
```